# Springboot MetricRepository

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I am trying to use

```
org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.repository.MetricRepository
```

to spit out metrics with

```
private final MetricRepository repository;

@Autowired
public MetricExporterService(MetricRepository repository) {
    this.repository = repository;
}
```

but since I am using Java 1.8 I get

```
Parameter 0 of constructor in com.example.actuator.MetricExporterService required a bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.repository.MetricRepository' that could not be found.
    - Bean method 'actuatorMetricRepository' not loaded because @ConditionalOnJava (older than 1.8) found 1.8
```

Is there a way of overriding this behavior?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With java 8, you should rather use `CounterService`, `GaugeService` and `BufferMetricReader`:

```
@Autowired
private BufferMetricReader metricReader;

@Autowired
private CounterService counterService;

@Autowired
private GaugeService gaugeService;

...

counterService.increment("metric1");
gaugeService.submit("metric2", 10d);
metricReader.findAll();
```

[Spring Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle):

> The default implementation of GaugeService and CounterService provided
>   by Spring Boot depends on the version of Java that you are using. With
>   Java 8 (or better) the implementation switches to a high-performance
>   version optimized for fast writes, backed by atomic in-memory buffers,
>   rather than by the immutable but relatively expensive Metric type
>   (counters are approximately 5 times faster and gauges approximately
>   twice as fast as the repository-based implementations).
>
> ...
>
> [Note] The old MetricRepository and its InMemoryMetricRepository
>   implementation are not used by default if you are on Java 8 or if you
>   are using Dropwizard metrics.
>
> ...
>
> To record your own metrics inject a CounterService and/or GaugeService
>   into your bean. The CounterService exposes increment, decrement and
>   reset methods; the GaugeService provides a submit method.